# How to combine different pictures into a single picture?

Tags: software-recommendation

I have 12 pictures of my iPhone.

At the moment I can see them on my computer as 1 picture each. I want to combine them so that I can see 4 pictures within a single image.

Is the possible?

I want them to combine just like 4 boxes for A4 so I can print them off.

Free software will be priority please

Comment: You can do it in GIMP. I'm not giving steps since I don't use gimp

Answer (score 1):

do following steps

1. download picasa and install it
2. add your folder to picasa by main menu>file>add folder to picasa..  then select screen captures in tray.
3. in main menu > create > picture collage
4. do attached images settings[image: picasa settings]